# How to insert html page (URL) to SQLite Database?

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiwebview, sqlite

i am using couple of html pages which are loaded in UIWebView , there is a  add to favorite button when clicked URL of the html page should be stored in SQLite Database..
how to do this ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save them in NSUserDefaults as follow:

**Saving**

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

// saving an NSString

```
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

**Retrieving**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

**// getting an NSString**

```
 NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

then use it in your code to retrieve the URL of the html page

to link it with your webView :

```
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Thanks lots :) do you know how to use ios facebook comment widget in iPad app?